# Which of the following becomes true when $\in$ is inserted in place of the blank? Which become true when $\subseteq$ is inserted?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can someone please verify my answers?

> Which of the following becomes true when $\in$ is inserted in place of the blank? Which become true when $\subseteq$ is inserted?
>
> (a) $\{\phi\}$ __ $\{\phi, \{\phi\}\}$
>
> (b) $\{\phi\}$ __ $\{\phi, \{\{\phi\}\}\}$
>
> (c) $\{\{\phi\}\}$ __ $\{\phi, \{\phi\}\}$
>
> (d) $\{\{\phi\}\}$ __ $\{\phi, \{\{\phi\}\}\}$
>
> (e) $\{\{\phi\}\}$ __ $\{\phi, \{\phi, \{\phi\}\}\}$

(a) $\subseteq$ and $ \in$

(b) $\subseteq$

(c) $\subseteq$

(d) $\in$

(e) nothing

Comment: Right. Not that it matters, but should $\phi$ have been $\varnothing$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Doesn't matter.

Comment: I have this feeling that this question was asked before. At least once.

Answer (score 0):

My remarks:

- a) ok
- b) ok
- c) ok
- d) ok
- e) ok